# Can the "frequency" in the Fourier form of the Delta function ever be complex?

Tags: fourier-analysis, complex-integration, dirac-delta

In this form of the Dirac Delta function
$$\delta(x) =\mathcal{F}[1] =\frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i\zeta x} d\zeta.$$
does $\zeta$ always have to be real valued?

If I make the substitution $\zeta(t) = i \omega(t)$ I think I can get this other form of the Dirac Delta function
$$\delta(x) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_{- i \infty}^{i \infty}e^{-\omega x} d\omega.$$
In this form does $\omega(t)$ always have to be strictly imagnary, or could we think of $\omega$ as a more general path in the complex plane (which starts at $-i\infty$ an ends at $\infty$)?

Comment: There are two ways to think about this. One train of thought leads to a complex valued frequency, defined by the Laplace transform. In this view, $\zeta$ is always a purely real number because it is the imaginary part of a larger frequency. But one can also view $\zeta$ itself as being complex in its own right, like its application in the Paley-Wiener theorem.

Comment: The Laplace transform of $f(t)$ allows any complex value of $\zeta$, you should interpret it as the Fourier transform of $f(t)e^{-\sigma t}$ where $\sigma=-\Im(\zeta)$. The inverse Fourier transform on some vertical line converges to  $f(t)e^{-\sigma t}$ whenever it is a tempered distribution (this is more or less the domain of convergence problem in the Laplace transform)

Comment: Crossposted to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/538724/2451